# How to repeat code x times and change value in each repetiton?

Tags: python

Code:

```
path_count = ai_app.ActiveDocument.PathItems.Count
front_path = ai_app.ActiveDocument.PathItems(1)
```

I want to repeat `front_path` the same amount of times as `path_count`; its result is not fixed so it can vary, also I want each repetiton to change the int value inside `PathItems()` according to the repetiton.

For Example: when repetion 2 is happening the value must be 2.

**Note**: I know I can repeat the code using a loop, but I don't know how to change the value inside `PathItems()`.

Comment: Are you looking for more than the obvious `for i in path_count:` / `front_path = ai_app.ActiveDocument.PathItems(i+1)`?

Comment: " I know I can repeat the code using a loop, but I don't know how to change the value inside PathItems()" how would you do the loop?